# javascript crop image to canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to crop the image based on specific area, below example how to crop image so it becomes only the things (pixel, data...) inside blue line, and delete things (pixel, data...) outside the box?

Below code is what I tried, after canvas draw new image, not correct area what I want, do I miss something, how to fix it ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Please don't provide plugin as an answer, and css crop is not what I'm looking for.

**UPDATE**
https://jsfiddle.net/xqpdtq76/
I update the fiddle and below code, the image naturalWidth is different with css width, so I need to convert the crop x,y,width,height (sx,sy,sw,sh) to fit the natural image size and crop the image.
the result it seems work to crop the correct area but image is not correct scale .. I don't get why

```js
var crop = function() {

  var transformMediaBlock = $('.mediaBlock');
  var transformCropInner = $('.transformCropInner');
  var transformCropLimit = $('.transformCropLimit');
  var canvasContainer = $('.canvasContainer')

  var canvasWidth = $(transformCropLimit).width();
  var canvasHeight = $(transformCropLimit).height();
  var canvas = $('<canvas/>',{'class':''}).width(canvasWidth).height(canvasHeight);
  canvas = canvas.appendTo($(canvasContainer));
  var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

 var limitLeft = transformCropLimit.offset().left;
  var limitTop = transformCropLimit.offset().top;
  var limitRight = limitLeft + transformCropLimit.width();
  var limitBottom = limitTop + transformCropLimit.height();
  console.log('limitLeft:'+limitLeft)
  console.log('limitRight:'+limitRight)
  var imageLeft = transformMediaBlock.find('img').offset().left;
  var imageTop = transformMediaBlock.find('img').offset().top;
  var imageRight = imageLeft + transformMediaBlock.find('img').width();
  var imageBottom = imageTop + transformMediaBlock.find('img').height();
  console.log('imageLeft:'+imageLeft)
  console.log('imageRight:'+imageRight)

  if (limitLeft <= imageLeft) {
    var sx = 0;
  } else {
    var sx = limitLeft - imageLeft;
  }
  console.log('sx:'+sx)

  if (limitTop <= imageTop) {
    var sy = 0;
  } else {
    var sy = limitTop - imageTop;
  }
  console.log('sy:'+sy)

  if (limitLeft <= imageLeft) {
    var l =  imageLeft;
  } else {
    var l = limitLeft;
  }
  if (limitRight <= imageRight) {
    var r = limitRight;
  } else {
    var r = imageRight;
  }
  var sw = r - l;
  console.log('sw:'+sw)

  if (limitTop <= imageTop) {
    var t = imageTop;
  } else {
    var t = limitTop;
  }
  if (limitBottom <= imageBottom) {
    var b = limitBottom;
  } else {
    var b = imageBottom;
  }
  var sh = b - t;
  console.log('sh:'+sh);


  var dx = 0;
  var dy = 0;
  var dw = sw;
  var dh = sh;

  console.log('naturalWidth:'+transformMediaBlock.find('img')[0].naturalWidth);
  console.log('naturalHeight:'+transformMediaBlock.find('img')[0].naturalHeight);
  console.log('cssWidth:'+transformMediaBlock.find('img').width());
  console.log('cssHeight:'+transformMediaBlock.find('img').height());
  var ratio = (transformMediaBlock.find('img')[0].naturalWidth / transformMediaBlock.find('img').width());
  console.log('ratio:'+ratio);
  sx = sx*ratio;
  sy = sy*ratio;
  sw = sw*ratio;
  sh = sh*ratio;
  console.log('sx*ratio:'+sx)
  console.log('sy*ratio:'+sy)
  console.log('sw*ratio:'+sw)
  console.log('sh*ratio:'+sh)
  ctx.drawImage(transformMediaBlock.find('img')[0],
    sx, sy, sw, sh,
    dx, dy, dw, dh
  );
  
};


$('#container').on('click', '.action.crop', function (e) {
  var transformMediaBlock = $('.mediaBlock');
  transformMediaBlock.find('img').on('load', function() {
    crop();
  }).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });
});
```

```css
.mediaBlock {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mediaBlock img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.transformCropLimit {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.transformCropInner {
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="content main">
    <div class="transformCropLimit">
      <div class="transformCropInner">
        <div class="mediaBlock">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EdQs9jA.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="action crop">Crop</div>
  </div>
  <div class="canvasContainer"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried it with an image that's 300px wide? It looks in your fiddle like you're using a much larger image that is being resized via css

Comment: Testing using [this placehold.it](https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97225&w=300&h=225) image, it seems to be working, but your canvas is outputting the wrong size

Comment: thanks for reply , I figure out it seems crop area base the original image size, not css style. so I think I have to convert the sw sh to fit original image size

Comment: I can't get how to covert sx sy...   tried to find a way drawimage scale same size as css, then crop it

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this, but I think that pulling an image from imgur and cropping it in canvas won't allow you to extract the data because of CORS restrictions. I know this is true for video, and I assume the canvas is tainted by an outside source as well if it is an image...

Comment: @somethinghere I add `img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');` and it fix cors

Comment: Yeah, that works where supported. But this does _not_ work on Safari (safari has not implemented CORS) and throws some nasty errors so be aware that it isn't that easy for now!

Comment: @somethinghere ouch I see it , thanks for remind , try google find a way now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### To crop image

Create a canvas the size of the crop area, then draw the image on that canvas. For example if you have a 500 by 400 image and you want to crop it to the top left 100,100, and bottom right 200,200

```
var crop = {
   top : 100,
   left : 100,
   right : 200,
   bottom : 200,
}
```

Create a canvas the correct width and height

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = crop.right - crop.left;
canvas.height = crop.bottom - crop.top;
```

Then draw the image onto that canvas so that the top left 100,100 is at the canvas origin 0,0

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // so we can draw
ctx.drawImage(image, -crop.left, -crop.top);
```

And that is how you create a cropped image (Note canvas is a HTMLImageElement)

### If you have scaled images.

```
var w = image.width;
var h = image.height;
```

and you draw it on a canvas at a scale

```
var myScale = 0.5; // half scale
```

and you want to crop it via the scaled canvas coordinates

```
var crop = {  // the canvas coordinate system
   top : 100,
   left : 100,
   right : 200,
   bottom : 200,
}
```

Your image scaled is in the canvas coordinate system with top left at (0,0) and its width and height are `w * scale`, `h * scale` To crop it just scale the image when you draw it.

Create the canvas.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = crop.right - crop.left;
canvas.height = crop.bottom - crop.top;
```

draw the image scaled and offset in the image coordinates

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // so we can draw
ctx.scale(scale,scale);
ctx.drawImage(image, -crop.left / scale, -crop.top / scale); // convert offset to 
                                                             // image coordinate system
```

Comment: I think you missed OP's real problem here: his image's naturalWidth is 2048, while he displays it at 300px. drawImage uses the naturalWidth.

Comment: ?? thanks for reply but this show things same in my question

Comment: yes my problem is I can't get covert sy sx sw sh with naturalWidth

Comment: @user1775888 You need the image size, then you can scale it. I have added info on how to scale and clip and modified your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/blindman67/gqc6bdw0/ so that it loads the image in javascript, that way you can get the image pixel size, because if you load it via the DOM you lose that information. Also I find jQuery makes everything so complex so fiddle just does it in JS you can add the jQuery stuff

Comment: Thanks I just found reason not get correct data is because use jquery set canvas width height,  but I use pure js it work, don't know why??

Comment: Because jQuery sets the canvas.style.width that set the display size while canvas.width is the element's  attribute that changes the resolution

Comment: @Blindman67 oh thanks!! I have question if I drawimage create small canvas and convert back to image or   drawimage create big canvas(original image natural size) convert back to image ,  does the two image result will be different?

Comment: @user1775888 image size is called resolution which is the number of pixels across and down. The canvas.width and canvas.height attributes determine the canvas resolution. If you draw on a canvas that has a high resolution then the image will be different than one drawn on a low resolution canvas. Reducing the resolution of an image loses information (one pixel is the mean of many), converting that low resolution image to high res will not get back the lost pixels and result in a low quality image.

Comment: @Blindman67 so if I use 400x400 image draw canvas 100x100  then convert back to image the result image will be different with 400x400 image draw 400x400 convert back to image  right??  and does the 2nd image 400x400 from canvas covert back, will be different with original image?

Comment: @user1775888 Sorry I do not understand the question. If you need to know just do the conversion and compare the results.